# CRA embedded in express app breaks express routing

Tags: express, routes, create-react-app

I have created an CRA app and have a couple express routes loading the CRA build files, for example:

```
app.get('/files', async (req, res, next) => {
        ...
        try {
            res.format({
                html: function() {
                    const fileLoc = './public/react_ui/build/index.html';
                    const stream = fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(fileLoc));
                    stream.pipe(res);
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            next(e);
            res.redirect(SEE_OTHER.http_status, '/login');
        }
    });
```

Prior to added the CRA, the express app exposed the `/public` folder like this:

```
// access to express App code files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Now that I have the CRA app embedded, I wanted to expose the build files like this, otherwise the `index.html` file created by building the `CRA` does not know where the `/static/js/*` are:

```
// access to React App build files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/react_ui/build'));
```

However, it breaks the express routing. For instance, when I logout of the app, it is supposed to send me to the endpoint `/` and this checks if I am logged in or not, if not, then it is supposed to send me to the login page like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
...
    isLoggedIn(req, function(status) {
        switch (status.status) {
            case 200:
                res.redirect(303, '/loader');
                break;
            default:
                res.redirect(303, '/login');
        }
    });

});
```

However, this is what is breaking. If I remove the command to expose the `/build` folder above, then the routing works again and I am sent to the login page, but accessing the CRA pages breaks, because the build files are `NOT FOUND`.

```
// access to React App build files - if removed, routing works again
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/react_ui/build'));
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening? I don't know if this is a react app issue, an express issue, or something else. Any insights would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have conflicting routes.

**app.js**

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + 'path/to/static/build'));

// Dont use '/' as it used for static route.
app.use('/auth', (req, res) => {
  ...
  isLoggedIn(req, function(status) {
        switch (status.status) {
            case 200:
                res.redirect(303, '/loader');
                break;
            default:
                res.redirect(303, '/login');
        }
    });
})
```

Note you can use whatever route for static build. I have given general convention.

Comment: thanks for the comment, so yes, it is related to the route. I fixed it by changing the react build related express command to: 

`app.use('/static', express.static(path.resolve('./public/react_ui/build/static')));`

However, now my server is slow when loading any page. Any idea why?

Comment: You need to web pack your static files to be optimal and minified. Also load also depends on your server.